# sum only the odd numbers in the list, easy to do with for loop but how about while loop?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I tried writing this for this specific list but it keeps crashing, what can I change?

```
items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990]
summa = 0
n = 0
while n < len(items):
   num = items[n]
   if num % 2 != 0:
      continue
   summa += num
   n += 1
print(summa)
```

Comment: The `continue` makes it skip `n += 1` when it finds an odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increment `n` in your `if` block as well.

```py
if num % 2 != 0:
  n += 1
  continue
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comment, the cleaner solution would be to increment n before the if block, to prevent duplicate code:

```py
while n < len(items):
   num = items[n]
   n += 1
   if num % 2 != 0:
      continue
   summa += num
print(summa)
```

Comment: Why not just move it to before the `if`?

Comment: even better/cleaner solution

Comment: Or invert the `if` so there is no need for `continue`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers as pointed out `n += 1` is never reached when the `if` is true, so you have an infinite loop.

Instead of `while` loop you can use generator expression

```
print(sum(item for item in items if item % 2)) # 701
```

Comment: Python is simply awesome, changing 8  lines of code into just 1.

Comment: `sum(filter((2).__rmod__, items))` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need not to put continue it just keeps looping through while without incrementing the value of n.
Instead do the below changes:

```
items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990]
summa = 0
n = 0
while n < len(items):
   num = items[n]
   if num % 2 != 0:
      summa += num
   n += 1
print(summa)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to count up if *num % 2 != 0*

```
items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990]
summa = 0
n = 0
while n < len(items):
   num = items[n]
   if num % 2 != 0:
      n += 1
      continue
   summa += num
   n += 1
   print(summa)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of continue keyword. Just remove it and if the number is odd then add it to summa else do nothing. In both cases the value of n is incremented by 1 because it is outside the if block.

```
items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990]
summa = 0
n = 0
while n < len(items):
    num = items[n]
    if num % 2 != 0:
        summa += num
    n += 1
print(summa)
```

This is the output you will get **701**.

[image: Screenshot of code and output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you:

```
items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990,1]
summa = 0
n = 0

while n < len(items):
    summa += items[n] if items[n]%2 != 0 else 0
    n+=1
print (summa)
```